# Error: Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, wolfram-mathematica

I'm having problems to solve a function in mathematica.
The function is a quality function for determining narcissist numbers:

```
n[x_] := Total[DigitCount[x]] 

QF[z_] := (Sum[IntegerDigits[z][[i]]*10^(n[z] - i), {i, n[z]}] - Sum[IntegerDigits[z][[i]]^n[z], {i, n[z]}])^2
```

The Function works correctly, but when I try using Solve[], it always gives me an error message.

```
Solve[QF[z] == 0, z]

Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

I have read in other threads that the problem could be that the overall expression is evaluated before the value of IntegerDigits is known. In those cases the solved the issue with Indexed[] or Hold[]. However, I tried both but it didn't work for me.

- [Raw object 1 cannot be used as an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987025/raw-object-1-cannot-be-used-as-an-iterator)
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14645/prevent-part-from-trying-to-extract-parts-of-symbolic-expressions

I would be very grateful for every suggestion you might have on this issue!

Comment: If I change your  to `QF[z_]:=(Print["z==",z];..rest of your def of QF..)` that will make `QF` print the value of `z` before it does the rest of your function.  That prints `z==z` every time I run it. Can you do exactly this and verify you get the same? That seems to hint that `Solve` may be trying to do some symbolic testing of your `QF` function and you only intended that it be given explicit numeric (integer!!!) values. That seems like it might explain why it is failing as you see. If instead of `Solve` I try `Select[Table[{z,QF[z]},{z,0,20}],#[[2]]==0&]` that shows every integer gives zero